# react-native: How to use asyncstorage with rocksdb?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rocksdb

I want to embed data into react-native app. I think we have to use asyncstorage. We can use rocksdb as storage for asyncstorage. Documentation does not give any example of this. Wondering how to use it with rocksdb.

Also, react-native docs mentions asyncstorage data being global. Does that mean asyncstorage data is accessible to all the apps?

Comment: i don't know y is this question -1'd without leaving any comments.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems too broad as written as it seems like you're looking for a tutorial to be written.  And to the second question ... it's only global within an application. iOS wouldn't allow two apps to share the storage.

Answer (score 2):

AsyncStorage is a core react-native API that allows you to store key value pairs. It's global in that it is accessible within anywhere in the app but obviously not to all apps because of iOS sandboxing. It works on its own, as is, independently of any other database systems.

RocksDB is a native key-value store that currently only has a native implementation. If you want to use it in your react-native project, you or someone else will have to write an API (bridge) so that it can be used through js. And that would have nothing to do with AsyncStorage.

EDIT: Apparently AsyncStorage tries to use RocksDB on the native side if it exists. Otherwise, it seems to simply save the data in a text file. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.m

Comment: This answer is a little misleading. The JS side of AsyncStorage in the React Native source tries to use RocksDB if the native side is there. Right now the native part of the code isn't included in the released source tree but it clearly exists within Facebook, presumably they'll include it in a released version at some point.

Comment: I asked on Twitter about when/if the RocksDB backend will be released and @Vjeux (React Native dev) says hopefully they will: https://twitter.com/almostobsolete/status/583640680821616640

Comment: Also see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/582. Looks like the issue was created by OP